# What is kpsexpand?

Tags: gnuplot

gnuplot is giving the error: "sh: kpsexpand: not found."

I feel like the guy in Office Space when he saw "PC LOAD LETTER". What the heck is kpsexpand?

I searched Google, and there were a lot of pages that make reference to kpsexpand, and say not to worry about it, but I can't find anything, anywhere that actually explains *what it is.*

Even the man page stinks:

```
$ man kpsexpand

kpsetool - script to make teTeX-style kpsetool, kpsexpand, and kpsepath available
```

Edit: Again, I'm not asking what to do -- I know what to do, thanks to Google. What I'm wondering is what the darn thing *is.*

Answer (score 2):

kpsexpand, kpsetool and kpsepath are all wrappers for kpsewhich that deals with finding tex-related files
kpsexpand is used to expand environment varibles.
Say $VAR1 is "Hello World" and $VAR2 is "/home/where/I/belong" then

```
$ kpsexpand $VAR1
```

will return

```
Hello World
```

and

```
$ kpsexpand $VAR2
```

will return

```
/home/where/I/belong
```

`kpsewhich` is reminiscent to `which` just like `which progname` will search the directories in the $PATH environment variable and return the path of the first found progname, `kpsewhich filename` will search the directories in the various tex-paths, fonts, packages, etc. for filename.

to find out more lookup kpsewhich either in man or on google, and check out the source of kpsexpand

```
less `which kpsexpand`
```

Cheers
/B2S

Answer (score 1):

This is on the first page of google search results for "kpexpand gnuplot":

http://dschneller.blogspot.com/2007/06/visualize-hard-disk-temperature-with.html

It says that you do not need to care about the error-messages.

Here is the manual page for kpsexpand:

http://linux.die.net/man/1/kpsexpand